# How to disable Textwatcher from EditText and enable it for another Edittext?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to make an App in Kotlin, which converts decimal, binary,base5,base7, and Hexa numbers.

The app has 5 Edittexts and a Textwatcher attached to the first one, when I enter a decimal number in it, it automatically converts the number (using doOnTextChanged) and fills the other EditTexts with their correct values.

But I have a huge problem now. When I try to enter a value in the second EditText my app crashes (Because of conflicting TextWatchers I assume).

Could you please give me an idea, of how I can disable the "doOnTextChanged" from the first EditText and enable it for the others? I would be forever grateful for any piece of Advice!

My Code below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var decimalnumber: EditText = findViewById(R.id.decimalnr)
    var binarynumber: EditText = findViewById(R.id.binarynumber)
    var base5number: EditText = findViewById(R.id.base5)
    var base7numbeer: EditText = findViewById(R.id.base7)
    var hexanumber: EditText = findViewById(R.id.hexa)

    decimalnumber.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->

        decimalnumber.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            try {
                var dnumber = decimalnumber.text.toString().toInt()
                if (dnumber > 0) {
                    var binary = Integer.toString(dnumber, 2)
                    var base5nr = Integer.toString(dnumber, 5)
                    var base7nr = Integer.toString(dnumber, 7)
                    var hexanr = Integer.toString(dnumber, 16)

                    binarynumber.setText(binary)
                    base5number.setText(base5nr)
                    base7numbeer.setText(base7nr)
                    hexanumber.setText(hexanr)
                }
            } catch (exception: NumberFormatException) {
                binarynumber.setText("")
                base5number.setText("")
                base7numbeer.setText("")
                hexanumber.setText("")

            }
        }
    }

    binarynumber.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->

        binarynumber.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->

            var binnumber = binarynumber.text.toString()
            var dnumber = Integer.valueOf(binnumber, 2)

            var base5 = Integer.toString(dnumber, 5)
            var base7 = Integer.toString(dnumber, 7)
            var hexa = Integer.toString(dnumber, 16)

            binarynumber.setText(binnumber)
            base5number.setText(base5)
            base7numbeer.setText(base7)
            hexanumber.setText(hexa)

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the `stack trace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a `TextWatcher` on `binaryNumber` that updates its text every time its text updates:

```
binarynumber.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
    ...
    binarynumber.setText(binnumber)
```

so you end up with a cycle of the `TextWatcher`'s update callbacks triggering updates that trigger callbacks that trigger updates... You have to be really careful about updating an `EditText` inside its own `TextWatcher` for this reason, maybe involving a flag you set while updating, so the callbacks can skip any further updates and let it complete.

It doesn't look like you even need to do it here though? You're just reading the contents of `binaryNumber` and setting that as its text again. Remove the `binarynumber.setText(binnumber)` line and it won't trigger the watcher again. But you do have to be careful about situations where a watcher on *textA* updates *textB*, which has a watcher that updates *textA*... same situation, involving multiple watchers. Having an `updating` boolean they can all see can help:

```
// a flag visible to all the watchers
var updating = false

textA.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
    // if an update is happening, don't go updating anything else!
    if (!updating) {
        // block anything else from forcing an update
        updating = true
        textB.setText("hi)
        // all done
        updating = false
    }
}
```

if `textB` checks `updating` in the same way, once `textA` does an update, `textB` will ignore it instead of triggering a response. And then the function in `textA` can complete and reset `updating`.

---

Also as far as I'm aware, that `doOnTextChanged` ktx extension adds a new `TextWatcher` every time you call it, so you're piling up mutiple watchers every time something gains or loses focus. Just set them once, during initialisation

Comment: THANK YOU!! I added the updating bool just like you said and now everything works as it should. No crashes nothing! Thank you again!

Comment: @Khanjali no worries! It's a good thing to get your head around, because you can run into it a lot (I did the other week!)